# ¿Cómo podría contar en un array de JSON?

Tags: javascript

Suponiendo que tengo un array de JSON que luce de la siguiente manera:

```
[
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': false
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  }
]
```

¿Cómo podría contar los elementos cuyo key `asistio === true`?

Comment: var jsonarray; jsonarray.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
}); recorre tu json con este codigo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Se puede usar `.filter` también, que lo hace un poco mas corto, ya que podemos aprovechar el hecho de que `asistio` es **true** o **false**:

```js
var arr = [{
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': false
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  }
]

var cant = arr.filter(o => o.asistio).length;

console.log(cant)
```

Answer (score 6):

Solo tienes que iterar por el array y contar asi:

```js
var data = [
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': false
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  }
];
var asistieron = 0;
data.forEach(function(dato) {
  if(dato.asistio) {
    asistieron++;
  }
});
console.log(asistieron);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo usaría reduce:

```
const n = date.reduce((acc, {asistio}) => 
  asistio === true
    ? acc + 1
    : acc;
), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Te comento que también puedes usar `map()`, que al iterar devuelve un array nuevo y te mostrará el resultado que esperas; solo es cuestión de observarlo

> Recorremos el array y en la clave asistio verificamos con el triple
>   signo `=` si es que su propiedad es true; de ser así sumamos uno al
>   contador que debe estar declarado por fuera, una vez hecho lo anterior
>   con un `console.log` lo imprimimos por fuera, usamos un `if` para comparar  > el valor que deseamos encontrar y en caso afirmativo hacer incrementar al contador

```js
let data = [
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': false
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  }
]

contador = 0
data.map((dato) => {
  if(dato.asistio === true){
    contador += 1
    
  }
})
console.log(contador)
```

Te comento además que como el valor que buscas contabilizar cuantas veces estas es booleano; basta con la sintáxis así dato.asistio ya que por defecto buscará primero aquellos valores que sean true, además puedes usar la sintaxis de `if` ternario que tiene su estructura de este modo: `(variable) ? valorAfirmatvo : valorFalso` del modo siguiente

```js
let data = [
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': false
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  },
  {
    'nombre': 'X',
    'asistio': true
  }
]

contador = 0
data.map((dato) => {
  (dato.asistio) ? contador += 1 : 0
})
console.log(contador)
```

Para mayor información sobre el método map() así como ejemplos que te dan mayo claridad de como funciona te dejo documentación de [referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/%60map%60)

Comment: Map reserva espacio en memoria y devuelve un array, si lo que se quieres es simplemente iterar por un iterable, usa forEach, ya que no se hace uso de memoria

Comment: @CarlosRamosar por eso mencioné que map genera un array nuevo y puede usarlo como opción